# Spring data jdbc with multiple data sources and multiple dialects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I have a spring boot application that uses spring data jdbc and connects to two databases. One of them is postgres and one is oracle. I access them via jdbc repositories (org.springframework.data.repository.Repository).

That works very well in general but all the repositories use the same dialect. How can I use different jdbc dialects based on the jdbc repository that is used for the query?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps someone else in the future:

It is possible to implement your own version of `JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean` and hard code the Dialect there. The custom class can then be used with the `@EnableJdbcRepositories` annotation.

Example configuration for an oracle database:

```
@EnableJdbcRepositories(basePackageClasses = my.oracle.DbRepository.class,
  jdbcOperationsRef = "secondaryNamedParameterJdbcTemplate",
  transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager",
  repositoryFactoryBeanClass = OracleRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

Example of custom factory bean:

```
public class OracleRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable>
extends JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {
   // override constructor and set dialect
   // override setDialect to be safe
}
```

If there is a more elegant solution please add it.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of setting the dialect, you may also need to set the Converter and `MappingContext`, if you need database specific JDBC converters.

I inject the application context into a configuration class (using `implements ApplicationContextAware` storing the context as a static), and then use that to retrieve my database specific Dialog, MappingContext and Converters.

Note: As of spring-data-relational version 3.2, the JdbcOperations, and DataAccessStrategy are passed in if set using `@EnableJdbcRepositories`, it is the other 3 mentioned above that need to be set using this method.

```
public class MyRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable>
        extends JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

    public MyRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMappingContext(RelationalMappingContext mappingContext) {
        JdbcMappingContext myContext = MyConfig.getBean("myJdbcMappingContext", JdbcMappingContext.class);
        super.setMappingContext(myContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDialect(Dialect dialect) {
        Dialect myJdbcDialect = MyConfig.getBean("myJdbcDialect", Dialect.class);
        super.setDialect(myJdbcDialect);
    }

    @Override
    public void setConverter(JdbcConverter converter) {
        JdbcConverter myConverter = MyConfig.getBean("myJdbcConverter", JdbcConverter.class);
        super.setConverter(myConverter);
    }
}
```